# Variable for function in php

Tags: php, mysql, function

Hi how to write php code for this, I have file contain list of data for example

```
  AA123_jane_G-1
  AA456_oshi_K-3
  AA789_pritt_P-4
```

I read my file using

```
function myfile(){

     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "_")) !== FALSE) {
    ..................
    ........
     .......
   //get $student_id, $name, $class,
}
```

I need to get username and password using student_id from file

```
function getusernameandpassword($student_id){

 ........
 .......
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT student_id, username, password FROM account WHERE student_id= '".$student_id."'");
 ........
 //get $username and $password from other remote server
 ....... }
```

after execute the both function, I want to gather all the information of that student and insert to DB

```
   function insertDB(){
 ........
 .......
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_info 
(student_id, username, password, name, class) VALUES ($student_id,$username,$password,$name,$class)")
 ........
 .......
 //insert all the paramater get from both function for each student to localhost DB}
```

My question, how I write this function in 1 script using php. How to return value and how to get the value to be input for other function

Comment: @new_bee_magento what is OOPS

Comment: apart from the fact that mysql_* function are deprecated and really, really should not be used any more: simply pass the variables as arguments to your functions.

Comment: thanks all. i write my script using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

to use a function's variable outside of the function, you either return the variable and assign it to another variable, or set the desired variable as `global` inside the function, for example:

```
function test(){
    global $variable;
}
```

and then you can use it any where inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

First off stop using the deprecated mysql functions you should be using PDO. Also back tick your field/columns/tables to avoid any clash with reserve words

If I understood you should be able to do this in a single SQL statement like

```
'INSERT INTO `user_info`(`student_id`, `username`, `password`, `name`, `class`) 
SELECT `student_id`, `username`, `password`, '.$name.','.$class.' FROM `account` WHERE `student_id`= '.$student_id.')'
```

See here for more info on the [INSERT...SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) syntax

By selecting variables (ie name and class) passed into the query string you can also insert the info not available in the account table (which I guess you are getting from the text file)

Comment: but im select the username and password from different server1 and insert into table from server 2. Can i still can use INSERT INTO SELECT statement??

Comment: thanks.. i write my script using PDO. Now it works.. haha.. it much easier than I thought

Comment: Nope you wouldn't be able to use insert select with different dB servers

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrays

```
function getusernameandpassword($student_id) {
    ....
    return array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
}

function insertDB($infos){
    ....
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_info (student_id, username, password, name, class) VALUES ($student_id, {$infos['username']}, {$infos['password']}, $name, $class)");
    ....
}
```

Or you could use objects

```
function getusernameandpassword($student_id) {
    ....
    return (object)array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
}

function insertDB($infos){
    ....
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_info (student_id, username, password, name, class) VALUES ($student_id, {$infos->username}, {$infos->password}, $name, $class)");
    ....
}
```

@mike-miller is right, stop using the deprecated mysql functions